# How to get complete details from request coming from gateway to services using Apollo Federation

Tags: graphql, nestjs, auth0, apollo-federation

I'm trying to implement Auth0 in Apollo Federation, I was able to implement it in its individual services (https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization/#Set-Up-API-Authorization) but if I'm trying to access the APIs thru the gateway, the header/payload is not being passed down to the services, hence its always unauthorized.

if the API is accessed thru individual services, the payload is being received and properly decoded from the header and works fine but if thru the gateway, its not being cascaded to the services that needs it.

Currently using a code-first implementation for it. I've also tried mirroring the module used in the services but it still doesn't work.

**sample payload in individual service**

```
{
  iss: 'issuer url here',
  sub: 'google-oauth2',
  aud: ['audience link'],
  iat: ,
  exp: ,
  azp: '',
  scope: '',
  permissions: [ 'sample:permission' ] 
}
```

**imports in the gateway**

```
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot(),
GraphQLGatewayModule.forRoot({
            server: {
                cors: true,
            },
            gateway: {
                serviceHealthCheck: true,
                serviceList: [
                    {
                        name: 'service',
                        url: `${process.env.SERVICE_URL}/graphql`,
                    },
                ],
            },
        }),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize header that's being used in internal request by using buildService option:

server.ts

```
    const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
        buildService: ({ url }) => new RequestHandler({ url }),
        serviceList,
    })
```

where RequestHandler class extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource:

```
import { RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from '@apollo/gateway'
import type { GraphQLRequest } from 'apollo-server-core'
import type express from 'express'

export class RequestHandler extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
    willSendRequest({ context, request }: { context: { req: express.Request }, request: GraphQLRequest }) {
        request.http?.headers.set('somethingFromOriginalRequestOrSomethingCustom', context.req.headers['something'])
    }
}
```